# Implement sort similar to radix

Tags: algorithm, sorting

hi i need to write sucj kind of sorting maybe it is  similary to  radix sort
and also (this is not homework  because i created it problem myself and please if anobody can help me) problem is like this
suppose  i have array   int x[]=new int[]{4,5,3,2,1};
let write it into  binary form
5 -0101
4- 0100
3-0011
2-0010
1-0001
i want to sort this elements by using bitwise operatos or check each bit  and if less exchange it can anybody help me
for example take 5 and 4    check first rightmost bit  0==0 so continue  in the  1 index also 1==1   next the same 0=0 and last one 1>0 it means that first element is greater then second so exchange it

> **Paraphasing:**
>
> I need to create a sort similar to radix.
>
> Suppose I have an array: `int x[] = new int[] {4, 5, 3, 2, 1};`
>
> Or, in binary form: `5-0101 4-0100 3-0011 2-0010 1-0001`
>
> I want to sort these elements by using bitwise operators or check each bit and (if less) exchange it. For example, consider 5 and 4:
>
> The leftmost or most significant bit (MSB) of 5 in binary is 0, as is the MSB of 4. Since `0 == 0` the process continues. The next two bits (0 then 1) are also equivalent. Finally the rightmost or least significant bit (LSB) of 5 is 1 whereas the LSB of 4 is 0, indicating that the two values should be exchanged.

Comment: What happened to your punctuation!?

Comment: @Greg S: Thanks, sometimes I can't help but try to decipher questions that I might otherwise be interested in; and I think it helps the community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `k`-th bit of an `int x`, you can do the following:

```
int bit = (x >> k) & 1;
```

Here's a test harness:

```
    int xs[] = {4,5,3,2,1};
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        for (int x : xs) {
            int bit = (x >> k) & 1;
            System.out.format("|%s|  ", bit);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

This prints (with annotation)

```
x= 4    5    3    2    1  k=
  |0|  |1|  |1|  |0|  |1|  0
  |0|  |0|  |1|  |1|  |0|  1
  |1|  |1|  |0|  |0|  |0|  2
  |0|  |0|  |0|  |0|  |0|  3
```

The tricky bit here is the sign bit, i.e. bit 31 on an `int`. When it's `1`, it signifies a negative number. You may want to first have an implementation that only works for positive `int`, and then add support for negative number later.

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)